OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite AddOnsDatabase model once compiled. [Typescript]
Im using nextjs
i keep getting the error
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite AddOnsDatabase model once compiled.

to fix this error i am using the OR operator to check if the model already exists
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const AddOnsDatabaseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  limit: String,
  required: Boolean,
});

const AddOnsDatabase =
  mongoose.model("AddOnsDatabase") ||
  mongoose.model("AddOnsDatabase", AddOnsDatabaseSchema);
export default AddOnsDatabase;


this fixes the errors but messes up typescript as when i was using
const AddOnsDatabase = mongoose.model("AddOnsDatabase", AddOnsDatabaseSchema);

and used this model like this:
"use server";
import { connectDB } from "@/lib/mongodb";
import AddOnsDatabase from "@/models/AddOnsDatabase";
import { DBAddon } from "@/types/temp";
export async function GetAddOns(): Promise<DBAddon[]> {
  await connectDB();
  const addons = await AddOnsDatabase.find().lean();
  console.log(addons);
  if (!addons) return [];
  const addonsToReturn = addons.map((addon) => {
    return {
      id: addon._id ? addon._id.toString() : "",
      name: addon.name ? addon.name : "",
      limit: addon.limit ? addon.limit : "",
      required: addon.required ? addon.required : false,
    };
  });
  return addonsToReturn;
}

addons would have this type
const addons: (FlattenMaps<{
    name?: string | null | undefined;
    limit?: string | null | undefined;
    required?: boolean | null | undefined;
}> & {
    _id: Types.ObjectId;
})[]

but after using the OR operator const AddOnsDatabase = mongoose.model("AddOnsDatabase") || mongoose.model("AddOnsDatabase", AddOnsDatabaseSchema);
addons has type
const addons: (FlattenMaps<any> & Required<{
    _id: unknown;
}>)[]

please help me find a way to not get that error and also infer types automatically using Model.findById()
I have tried the above stated things
